# Canvas video CORS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, cors

I have the following code, obtained from http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/

```
$("#video").append('<video id="movie" style="display:none" autobuffer><source id="srcMp4" src="https://host-away-from-host.com/file.mp4" type=\'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"\' /></video>'+
'<canvas width="711" height="800" id="buffer" style="display:none"></canvas>'+
'<canvas width="711" height="400" id="output"></canvas>');

var outputCanvas = document.getElementById('output'),
    output = outputCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    bufferCanvas = document.getElementById('buffer'),
    buffer = bufferCanvas.getContext('2d'),
    video = document.getElementById('movie'),
    width = outputCanvas.width,
    height = outputCanvas.height,
    interval;


function processFrame() {
    buffer.drawImage(video, 0, 0);

    // this can be done without alphaData, except in Firefox which doesn't like it when image is bigger than the canvas
    var image = buffer.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
        imageData = image.data,
        alphaData = buffer.getImageData(0, height, width, height).data;

    for (var i = 3, len = imageData.length; i < len; i = i + 4) {
        imageData[i] = alphaData[i-1];
    }

    output.putImageData(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);
}

video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(processFrame, 40)
}, false);
```

It takes the video, and loads it into a canvas for transparency.

However, I'm using a CDN for my video, and Chrome isn't happy with this cross-origin data.

I've already set up the proper CORS headers (but would appreciate a checklist) in my CDN, but I have no idea how to implement these suggested changes to this code; http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html

Any advice on this matter would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: I deduced that `buffer.drawImage(video, 0, 0);` is the culprit, adding the cross-origin video to the buffer canvas. How do I make the video non cross-origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this bug report Firefox 12+ supports CORS videos:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=682299

How to make resources CORS aware:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Cross-Domain_Textures

Should apply to other modern browsers too, but I suggest you test out which browsers are modern.

Comment: Thanks Mikko! Even though I eventually ended up using an iframe for a page that was hosted on the same CDN as the video, I will definitely check that out! The iframe isn't a very elegant solution in my opinion.

Comment: You probably still need to keep the Flash / <iframe> fallback for old browsers around :(

Comment: Fortunately this project is evil and unfair in the way that old browsers are not only not supported, but even blocked. >:)

Comment: You must be one lucky developer

Comment: Nah, just aggressively progressive. I'm not making the next Facebook and my target market share isn't 100% (or even 10%), so I will not allow myself to get distracted from innovation in order to cater to three centenarians with six-year-old software on their computers -- I do however offer them a nice and easy-to-follow tutorial on how to get with the times in the way of a browser that doesn't suck. :)

Comment: [My test](http://meemoo.org/iframework/#gist/3754963). I can only get it to work in FireFox with ```video.crossorigin="anonymous"``` (not ```crossOrigin```... probably a bug). I can't get it to work in Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've set CORS up correctly on your remote CDN, you'll need to add `crossorigin="use-credentials"`  to your `<video>` tag.

it should look like this:

```
<video id="movie" style="display:none" preload="auto" crossorigin="use-credentials">
```

If you are using and s3 bucket, you can set the CORS to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I had to use `crossorigin="anonymous"` instead of `crossorigin="use-credentials"`, but that worked for me